# PowerShell Output Related to ADObject Properties

Tags: powershell, properties, active-directory

I'm trying to retain the `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount` object when searching and specifying return outputs; however, when selecting the outputs, additional fields are populating.  Questions:

1. Why is this is happening?
2. Is there a method, command, or filter to return only the specified parameters? (not the extra fields listed in the example below)
3. Is there a way to remove properties from the ADAccount Object? ($a in this example)
4. For the select method, is there a way to retain the original object formatting ? (I do not want a table and still need to reference the object later)

Running the following command:

```
$a = Get-ADUser $targetPerson -Properties Department, EmailAddress, Office, OfficePhone
```

returns:

```
Department        : ****
DistinguishedName : CN=1111,OU=2222,OU=3333,OU=4444,DC=5555,DC=6666
EmailAddress      : ****@mail.com
Enabled           : ****
GivenName         : ****
Name              : ****
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : ****
Office            : ****
OfficePhone       : ****
SamAccountName    : ****
SID               : ****
Surname           : ****
UserPrincipalName : ****
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ADUser` has a default set of properties it always returns, including for instance the distinguished name, the SID, and the account name. The parameter `-Properties` is for specifying which *additional* properties the cmdlet should return, because the default property set is just a small subset of all available properties.

To limit the output of `Get-ADUser` to a specific set of properties you need to pipe the output through `Select-Object`:

```
$props = 'Department', 'EmailAddress', 'Office', 'OfficePhone'
$a = Get-ADUser $targetPerson -Properties $props |
     Select-Object $props
```

Of course that will turn the `ADAccount` object into a custom object (`PSCustomObject`), but I don't think there's a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

The object Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount inherits members from the class it is created from.  Here are some of the inherited members - 
Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SID, and SamAccountName.

[More about AD Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adaccount?view=activedirectory-management-10.0)

I don't think you can create a Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount object with out those inherited members.

But if your project can accept a PSCustomObject then pipe $a to Select-object.

```
$a | Select-Object -Property Department, EmailAddress, Office, OfficePhone
```